# cells content grows out from CGRectZero as they appear in collectionViewCell (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have an app containing a UICollectionView.

When the collectionView first appears, the images contained in each cell are seen resizing from what looks like CGRectZero to their final size.

All the cells imageView's are explicitly sized in storyboard as constant height and width and in sizeForItemAtIndexPath I explicitly size the cells.

Just wondering if anybody else has come across this and found a solution.  From what I have read I need to add layoutIfNeeded.  I have tried adding this to viewWillAppear but it has not helped.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Image Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
    cell.messageDateLabel.text = dateString
    if let imageData = message.image {
        let messageImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
        cell.messageImage = messageImage
    }
    return cell
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let size = CGSizeMake(self.chatCollectionView.frame.size.width, Storyboard.ImageHeight)
        return size
    }
```

The collectionView is presented in a containerView as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageCollectionViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("imageCollectionViewController") as? imageCollectionViewController

        self.imageCollectionViewController!.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.addChildViewController(self.imageCollectionViewController!)
        self.addSubview(self.imageCollectionViewController!.view, toView: self.containerView)
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true
    }
```

Comment: thanks.  just provided code.  the collectionView and collectionView cell are set up in storyboard.

Comment: it is always coming out correct which is as expected because essentially it's returning a constant value for height and same superView's width.

Comment: i tried it just before returning size

Comment: Here's another question: you say "All the cells are explicitly sized in storyboard". What do you mean by that?

Comment: i tried it just before returning size.  the size printed out 375.0, 203.0 for every cell which is  correct size.  I mean that the cell's height is set to 203 in storyboard and constraints are such that the collectionView left and right side are pinned to superview.  and each cell exactly width of collectionView

Comment: i may be confusing things here.  It may be that the cell size is returning correct but the image is resizing, not the cell.  Since the image is the only thing in the cell, it appeared to me the cell was resizing.

Comment: The size of the cell as shown in the storyboard is irrelevant.

Comment: i have only one item in each cell which is an imageView.  The size is fixed width and height.  The height and width are set in storyboard as constants.

Comment: Does `message.image` always exist before any cells do?

Comment: yes.  message.image is loaded in viewDidLoad

Comment: Is there anything special about how we arrive that this view controller?

Comment: this viewController is a child ViewController of a Container View.  It is instantiated from storyboard in the viewDidLoad of the container View Controller and then added as a childView Controller and added as subView

Comment: You are not doing the "add child view controller" dance correctly. You are not giving `self.imageCollectionViewController!.view` any frame or constraints, and you are not calling `didMoveToParentViewController`.

Comment: @matt that's so much for your help. I have to step out but will try your suggestion when I'm back. Thanks for your time. I've upvoted your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this? I'm just throwing an idea.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Image Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
cell.messageDateLabel.text = dateString
    if let imageData = message.image {
    let messageImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
    cell.messageImage = messageImage
}
    cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1) 
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        }, completion: nil)

return cell
}
```

You probably want to apply the animation to cell.messageImage.

==========================================================================
I'm sorry I totally misunderstood your question. I thought you want the cell animation that grows from CGRectZero as it appears. I don't think you will get the correct layouts in viewDidLoad() specially when you have a viewcontrollr in a tabbarcontroller or navigationviewcontroller. you should set autoresizingMask to imageCollectionViewController.view or add your childviewcotroller in viewWillAppear() or do the following.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    self.imageCollectionViewController!.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds
}
```

Comment: What's funny is if I remove the tabbarhidden line the cells appear normally.